# Orderby in MONGODB

Tags: mongodb

I need help with Mongodb query "orderby" I would like to orderby the date: "dia" in this query:

```
db.pe_comp.aggregate([
                {$group : 
                  {_id :
                    {year:{$year:   "$dia"} 
                    },  
                    Sesiones:{$sum: "$sesiones"},
                    Usuarios:{$sum: "$usuarios"},
                    Visitas:{$sum:  "$n_vis_pag"},                      
                    Nuevas:{$sum:   "$por_new_ses"},    
                    Paginas:{$sum:  "$pag/ses"},
                    Rebote: {$sum:  "$por_rebote"}          
                    }         
                  }
                  ])
```

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

`$sort` stage is used to sort the data in the aggregation pipeline.

```
db.pe_comp.aggregate([
                       { 
                           $group : {
                               _id : {
                                   year : { $year : "$dia" } 
                               },  
                               Sesiones : { $sum : "$sesiones" },
                               Usuarios : { $sum : "$usuarios" },
                               Visitas : { $sum : "$n_vis_pag"},                      
                               Nuevas : { $sum : "$por_new_ses"},    
                               Paginas : { $sum : "$pag/ses"},
                               Rebote : { $sum : "$por_rebote"}          
                           }          
                       }, {
                           "$sort" : {
                                "_id.year" : 1
                           }
                       }
                    ])
```